# RDP Support by Windows OS Version

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

What versions of Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) are supported by recent versions of the Windows operating system, such as Windows XP and later?

This is the list of supported RDP versions I have documented:

- **Windows XP** --> 5.1, 5.2, 6.0, 6.1, 7.0
- **Windows Vista** --> 6.0, 6.1, 7.0
- **Windows 7** --> 6.1, 7.0, 7.1, 8.0, 8.1
- **Windows 8** --> 8.0, (8.1¹)
- **Windows 8.1** --> 8.1

¹ There is a bug with RDP 8.1 support on Windows 8.0--meaning it is not available.  As of 8/6/2014, this is a known issue Microsoft is working to resolve.

Comment: That looks about right. Win7 still has support, XP support was dropped before Win8 and Vista was a boundary release (like Win8), so support was dropped more quickly.